# On Premise Active Directory Federation Server - Application Groups

Tags: rest, api, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, adfs

I do not see [Application Groups] folder in my ADFS. How can I install it to see it in my AD FS Management?
I want my WEB API(REST) project to connect to ADFS for authentication. Additionally, I want to test my REST API Authentication without a login screen, please help in this as well. My API will be consumed by CRM users, who are already connected to ADFS. Now the requirement is to create an REST API which will be hit by CRM users and CRM user will pass a userid and password which will be authenticated by ADFS internally without login screen. How can I do that?

Any help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application Groups are only available in Server 2016 and 2019. They are available in the ADFS wizard by default.

In terms of sample code for calling API, have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-flows-scenarios).